# Git command to run diff and add at the same time?

Tags: git, git-config

I want to add a command to my git config so that when I type something like:

`git didd $FILE`

it will run a `git diff` and a `git add` for that file. I can do it with a simple bash script but I was wondering if it is possible in the gitconfig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with an *git alias* (which in this case is basically a bash script, but configured using gitconfig):

```
git config --global alias.didd '!git_didd() { git diff $1 ; git add $1 ; } ; git_didd'
```

Alternatively, you might also want to have a look at `git add --interactive` which also presents a diff of each individual change before adding it to the index. Using `git add -i`, you can also stage changes selectively, allowing you to commit only specific parts of edited files.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Plus that git add -i seems very interesting. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if you do `git add -p`, you get to interactively choose what's get added. It shows you the diff for a change of the file, and allows you to choose to add it or not.

From the [manual](http://jk.gs/git-add.html):

> -p
>   Interactively choose hunks of patch between the index and the work
>   tree and add them to the index. This gives the user a chance to review
>   the difference before adding modified contents to the index.